# Jenkins trigger the 2nd job when the first job fails

Tags: jenkins

There is a system that periodically runs on Jenkins and that I follow with selenium. (I'm checking its performance on "manager/status" page in Tomcat). I want it to trigger the second job, which will make detailed logging (*1) only when there is an error in the job. How can I do it?

When the first job is successful I can trigger the 2nd job but **what I need is to trigger the 2nd job when the first job fails**[image]

(*1)
I'm checking the geoserver performance. "http://serverip:port/geoserver/rest/monitor/requests.csv?order=totalTime;ASC" will download the performance values on geoserver server in "xls" format on jenkins server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your using a `freestyle` job, but this is where Jenkins `pipelines` shine.

```
node() {
    
    try {
        // do your testing
    } catch (Exception e) {
        build(job: 'detailed_logging')
    }
}
```

You can find more detail in the [build](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) step documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Parameterized Trigger (https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/) in your Post Build Actions.  In my example I did not pass any parameters to the new job.

[image]